# qt/c++ context menu - disable an item

Tags: c++, qt, qtreewidget

I'm currently developing an app such as the browser using Qt and c++.

I have create a contextual menu to allow on right click action such as delete, rename and add folder.

```
void MyTreeWidget::createContextMenu() {    
    contextMenu = new QMenu();
    setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::ActionsContextMenu);

    addFolderAction = new QAction("Add Folder", contextMenu);
    addAction(addFolderAction);
    connect(addFolderAction, SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(onAddFolderActionTree()));

    deleteAction = new QAction("Delete", contextMenu);
    addAction(deleteAction);
    connect(deleteAction, SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(onDeleteAction()));

    RenameAction = new QAction("Rename", contextMenu);
    addAction(RenameAction);
    connect(RenameAction, SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(onRenameAction()));

}
```

This is working fine. This contextual menu is used when you select a file or folder in my treewidget and make a right click. My issue is that I propose the "add folder" option even if I select a file. You can't create a folder inside a file.

What I want is to disable the option when a file is selected and enable it when it's a folder.

I can know if it's file or folder by getting the TreeWidgetItem class I have overloaded:

Thanks

Comment: Are you creating this context menu fresh every time the user right-clicks? Or is it created once and reused?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable QAction. In this case "Add Folder" menu item will be disabled:

```
addFolderAction->setEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the QAction::setEnabled(bool) method on your 'addFolderAction'.

One way to use it is like this:

```
void
MyTreeWidget::updateMenuActions()
{
    if(!contextMenu)
        return;
    bool addFolderEnabled = <check TreeWidgetItem here to enable / disable>;
    addFolderAction->setEnabled(bEnabled);
}
```

Call the updateMenuActions() method just before you display the context menu.

I actually prefer the code below in case you have situations where you can have NULL pointers to actions (for cases where you don't even add them):

```
void
MyTreeWidget::updateMenuActions()
{
    if(!contextMenu)
        return;
    bool addFolderEnabled = <check TreeWidgetItem here to enable / disable>;
    updateAction(addFolderAction, bEditEnabled);
}

void
MyTreeWidget::updateAction(QAction* pAction, const bool& bEnabled)
{
    if(pAction)
        pAction->setEnabled(bEnabled);
}
```

Enjoy.

Comment: when do I find the request to display the contextual menu ? I'm just calling the createcontextmenu when instantiate the MyTreeWidget class and after Qt handle it automatically

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you had that part... You need to overload 'contextMenuEvent' in MyTreeWidget:
virtual void contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent *event);
You can call the updateMenuActions method in there, and then just call:
QTreeWidget::contextMenuEvent(event);
to display the menu as before.

Comment: Thnaks it's done. I made at MouseEvent level. In case it not stable will move on contextMenuEvent overload